# How to resize image to maximize their dimensions into a panel without changing aspect ratio

Tags: java, image, aspect-ratio, maximize

I want to draw some images into a panel, I need that the images conserves their aspect ratio with the biggest dimensions to be drawn over a panel. So given the panel dimensions I must create a Java code to maximize that dimensions. The only ideas that I had needed to solve some linear programming, and I don't know how to do it in Java.
Which should be the easiest way to do what I need?

Comment: You want to fit the image as per the size of panel. Please confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method to get a re-sized `BufferedImage`.

```
private BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int width, int height)
        throws IOException {
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();
    return resizedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). It will dynamically resize the Icon to fill the space available to the label.

Comment: I think that what I need is a code to calculate the maximun dimensions that maintaining the aspect ratio gives me the new dimensions of the image because the image will be drawn into a panel using jmonkey game engine.I know how to resize a BufferedImage what i don´t know is how to calculate that dimensions